# The number of ways dividers can be placed between numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Can I please have a heuristic explanation of why the number of ways in which $r$ dividers can be placed between $n$ numbers, with repetition of dividers allowed, is ${n+r}\choose{n}$? Thanks.

Comment: think in n numbers, now divide it in r sets. consider each number like a sign "." and the division in r sets with "/" symbol. at the end you will have some like this ".../../...././....". If you can count the number of characters you will get n+r. Now the question is ¿How many options do I have to put r "/" symbols between groups of "." symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any placement of the dividers results in a row of $n+r$ symbols, namely the $r$ dividers and the $n$ numbers. And the placement is completely determined if you know which $r$ of the $n+r$ positions contain the dividers (because the numbers are supposed to be in  increasing order). So counting the placements amounts to counting the ways to choose $r$ out of the $n+r$ available positions.